# Find a function with general shape as a parabola and $f(0) = m$ and $f(1/2) = t$ where $m, t \in \Bbb R$.

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I have a relatively simple function design problem that I don't quite remember how to solve. Here are the parameters:

- function of the general shape $-x^2$
- $m$ and $t$ are constants
- $f(0) = m$
- $f(1/2) = t$
- $t$ $>$ $m$

The left side of the parabola should intersect with the y axis @ $m$ and the top / max point should hit at $f(1/2)$ which also $= t$. How would I go about designing this function?

Comment: Yes, t >= m. Can t = m? If t must > m, so be it.

Comment: $t\ne m$ since $t$ is the maximum $y$-value.

Comment: I guess theoretically it would just be a line y=t, y=m in that case.

Comment: That’s not a parabola, unless you’re including degenerate ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you know that:$$f(x)=t-a(x-1/2)^2\tag{vertex formula}$$and$$f(x)=-ax^2+bx+m\tag{standard form}$$so$$\begin{align}t-a(x-1/2)^2&=-ax^2+ax+t-\frac14a=-ax^2+bx+m\end{align}\\t-\frac14a=m\implies a=4(t-m)\\a=b\implies b=4(t-m)$$

> $$f(x)=-4(t-m)x^2+4(t-m)x+m$$

Comment: Doesn't look quite right. I plugged in m = .05, t = .2 and it is a smiley parabola and f(1/2) != t. Also, I have a lot to research to understand your process. For example, I'm not sure what a vertex formula is. What level math is that from?

Comment: @Dan You got upward parabola because $0.05 - 0.2 < 0$ so the first coefficient becomes +ve. Try $ m > t$.

Comment: t > m is one of the constraints of the problem. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Well I believe I accidentally fixed the function:

> $$f(x)=-4(t-m)x^2-4(m-t)x+m$$

Now I just need to understand the process for designing the function... lol

Comment: So in Simply Beautiful Art's solution, I think he made an error solving for a. $a$ = 4($t$-$m$) I'm going to see if I can edit his solution and mark it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Dan believe I fixed it. (was asleep during your comments)

Comment: You added a new error. $b=-4(m-t)$

Comment: @Dan $-4(m-t)=4(t-m)$

Comment: touché.........